# How set delay for the element using JavaScript 'readyState'?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I write auto tests for web app and I have a problem with delay. I don't want to use sleeps in my script, so I wrote the next:

```
public bool WaitForPageToLoadCompletely()
        {
            return new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(d =>
            ((IJavaScriptExecutor)d).ExecuteScript("return document.readyState").Equals("complete"));
        }
```

But it works only for whole page, but not for the elements on the page.

I am looking something like this, but for the element.

Thank you!

Comment: You don't have another command to wait for elements as well, a workaround would be to add a wait after a specific element for each page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Element doesn't have 'a ready state'. You have to wait until element is find-able or for its attribute property to have a value that you're expecting (e.g. if it's hidden, you have to wait until it's visible - e.g.:

```
        {
            return new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(d =>
           !d.FindElement(By.Id("Id").GetAttribute("style").Contains("display: none"));
        }
```

Comment: Thank you! In my case, the page is loaded quickly then the element on it, and I don't want to use sleeps.